# Person/people detection package for 2D-based camera

Tags: ros, image, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to know if there exist any person/people detection ROS package(s) that uses 2D image data as an input. What I'm aware of, lots of ROS packages available for are meant for the use with Kinect or any 3D-based camera.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154141/person/people-detection-package-for-2d-based-camera/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to check out HOG detector for OpenCV which tries to detect standing pedestrians, although you're going to get a lot of false positives and missed detections from it. Also, it seems they only have documentation on the website for the [GPU implementation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html) (i.e. using CUDA) and you'll have to look elsewhere for examples of the CPU implementation.

Another possibility to check out is the OpenCV [face detector](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html). Some ROS packages that use this are [face_detector](http://wiki.ros.org/face_detector) (uses stereo images though) and [pi_face_tracker](http://wiki.ros.org/pi_face_tracker?distro=groovy) (for Groovy though).

In general, detecting people from a moving robot with a monocular camera is still a very difficult and open problem. If your camera is stationary then the problem can be simplified through background subtraction but I don't have any references for that.

For help with using OpenCV in ROS, checkout the [vision_opencv](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv) package.

Edit: I uploaded my implementation of both of these in a ROS package on Github: https://github.com/angusleigh/hog_haar_person_detection_ros

---

Originally posted by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) with karma: 438 on 2014-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Phelipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21088/phelipe/) on 2015-03-09**:
@angus Can this code detect people (body) or just faces?

**Comment by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on 2015-03-09**:
It can detect both. Give it a shot but don't expect very robust performance from it unless you combine it with a tracking-by-detection method (e.g., a Kalman filter with outlier rejection), geometric constraints (e.g., filtering based on size) or background subtraction.

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2015-07-13**:
To which topics this node subcribes, pls post me list of topics it subscribes and publishes.